# Table style should be seperated from the rest of content

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have a table like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/DSvb7/

It currently works normally. However, when I copy paste this on my website, things get messy. For example, texts always appear in bottom, sometimes out of table.

I guess it is taking some of the table styles from CSS. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please point a link to your website instead to debug where the problem is occuring...

Comment: @Luc Laverdure; It is: http://www.sobafire.com/

The section I am speaking about is "En popüler Buildler" area just right below the slider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies within the width of your elements:

You have a total width of 360px, get your elements to smaller widths that fit within the box you have and it should work fine.

Comment: I have lowered the width to 200px, but it's still the same, Luc.

Comment: change your valign to vertical-align: middle;